# context is null in isolated process

Tags: android, service, android-googleapiclient

I have the next method:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}
```

The method should run in service with isolatedProcess="true", the problem is the context object becomes null in the isolated Process, how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

try to get context with **getApplicationContext()**.
and the **context** you are using may be getting destroyed thats why you are getting null.